# How do I make elements trigger to appear one after another, with a small interval?

Tags: javascript, scroll, triggers, intervals

I have a series of four elements. The first of which (#pro1) will appear on scrolling to a particular point on the page (this currently works), and the following three will trigger to appear one after another, with a small changeable interval in between each.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! A huge thank you in advance!

Here is the code for the first element, just needing to make the others appear after this one appears (#pro2, #pro3, #pro4, etc)

```
<script>
  $(window).one("scroll", function() {
      $('#pro1').each(function () {
           var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop(),
           bottomOfWindow = topOfWindow + $(window).height();

           var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

           if(imagePos < bottomOfWindow-200 && imagePos >= topOfWindow-500){
                $(this).addClass('bigEntrance2'); 
           }else{
                $(this).removeClass('bigEntrance2');
           }
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: take a look at setTimeout function: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: It would be useful to have html y css as well. Also, why are you using each with a ID selector? you are supossed to have just one.

Answer (score 1):

The key is using [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to call repeatedly the function that will create (or show if they are already created) the next elements.

It is important to not forget to [clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) the interval when the job is done.

Without the html and the css is difficult to realise exactly what you want to achieve, but from the next example you shouldn't have problems to update yours.

---

```js
var interval = null;
var elementId = 1;
var numElements = 4;
var delay = 1000; //ms


$(document).ready(function()
{
    //your first "pro1" element show up
    var element = "<div>Im the pro" + elementId + " element!</div>";
     $('body').append(element);   
    //in that moment we set the interval
    interval = setInterval(show_next_element, delay);
});


function show_next_element()
{
    //increment the counter elementId
    elementId++;
    //create the next element
    var element = "<div>Im the pro" + elementId + " element!</div>";
    //add it to the DOM
     $('body').append(element);   
    //when our last element is created we clear the interval
    if(elementId >= numElements)
        clearInterval(interval);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps!